# How to just pass an object in post method and just retrieve it as such?

Tags: node.js

We are using method called flask_api which has the parameter.

Our need is, we need to pass that parameter inside request.post

Can anyone please help as we are beginners in node.js

```
async flask_api(turnContext){
                var res;
                var fs = require('fs');
                var request = require('request');
                var formData = {image1: fs.createReadStream('D:/my_app/demo.png')}
                var json_body = "" ;
                var obj_value= ""
                function initPromise(turnContext)
                {return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) 
                {

                    console.log("print turn context",turnContext); //we are getting the value in turncontext
                    console.error('before post call...:1');
                    request.post({url:'http://127.0.0.1:5002/',formData: formData}, function(err, httpResponse, body) 
                    {
                        if (err) {
                        console.log("response", reject(err));
                        return JSON.stringify(err);
                        }
                        else{
                            while(1==1){
                            if(body != undefined){
                                break;
                            }
                            }
                        json_body = JSON.parse(body);
                        resolve([json_body,turnContext]);//here we are not able to get the turncontext
                        }
                    });
                })
                }
```

Comment: What error are u getting?

Comment: Hi @SagarChaudhary, its undefined the value is not coming

Comment: @SagarChaudhary and because its an object i couldnt able to pass it with formData also

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
var req = request.post({ url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5002/' }, (err, resp, body) => {
    if (err) {
       res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
       res.send(resp);
    }
});
var form = req.form();
form.append('file', fs.createReadStream('D:/my_app/demo.png'));
```

In your case:

```
async flask_api(turnContext){
                var res;
                var fs = require('fs');
                var request = require('request');
                var formData = {image1: fs.createReadStream('D:/my_app/demo.png')}
                var json_body = "" ;
                var obj_value= ""
                var tempContext;
                function initPromise(turnContext)
                {return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) 
                {
                   tempContext = turnContext;
                    console.log("print turn context",tempContext); //we are getting the value in turncontext
                    console.error('before post call...:1');
                    request.post({url:'http://127.0.0.1:5002/',formData: formData}, (err, httpResponse, body) =>
                    {
                        if (err) {
                        console.log("response", reject(err));
                        return JSON.stringify(err);
                        }
                        else{
                            while(1==1){
                            if(body != undefined){
                                break;
                            }
                            }
                        json_body = JSON.parse(body);
                        resolve([json_body,tempContext]);//here we are not able to get the turncontext
                        }
                    });
                })
            }
```

Comment: thanks but our problem is turnContext (object) we need to get inside the request.post as i mentioned in the code with comment (//) first turnContext in the console.log i am getting the value but in resolve the trunContext value is not coming its undefined

Comment: You need to use arrow function in your callback. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar: with arrow function in callback i tried to print turnContext in console but still facing the same error, turnContext object value is not coming inside that

Comment: request.post({url:'http://127.0.0.1:5002/',formData: formData}, (err, httpResponse, body) =>
                    {console.log(turnContext); // i am getting an error the object value is not coming on it
                        if (err) {
                        console.log("response", reject(err));
                        return JSON.stringify(err);
                        }
                        else{

Comment: I know that. Its weird. You should get it now. Never seen such a case. You need to upload a sample project in order for me to check

Comment: how to attach the whole file? its actually one js file

Comment: Can u check the updated code, I have tried using a globle variable tempContext and assigning turnContext to it and then accesssing tempContext

Comment: You can upload on github

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Note that I refactored your code (how I would have done it).

Server (for test purposes)

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var server = http.createServer().listen(8124);

server.on('request', function(request,response) {

   if (request.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';

        // append data chunk to body
        request.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;

        });

        // data transmitted
        request.on('end', function () {
            var post = querystring.parse(body);
            console.log(post);
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            response.end(JSON.stringify('body\n'));
        });
    }
});
console.log('server listening on 8124');
```

Client

```
function initPromise(turnContext) {

    var res;
    var fs = require('fs');
    var request = require('request');
    var formData = {image1: "hello"}
    var json_body = "" ;
    var obj_value= "";

    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
        console.log("print turn context",turnContext); //we are getting the value in turncontext
        console.error('before post call...:1');
        request.post({url:'http://localhost:8124/',formData: formData}, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else{
                if (body != undefined) {
                    json_body = JSON.parse(body);
                    resolve([json_body,turnContext]); //here we are not able to get the turncontext
                } else {
                    reject('body undefined');
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

async function flask_api(turnContext) {

    var result = initPromise(turnContext);
    console.log("result", result);
    result.then(

        // fulfillment
        function (val) { //this is where you get the value passed to resolve()
            console.log(val);
        }).catch(
            //log the rejection reason
            (reason) => {
                console.error(reason);
            }
        );
}

flask_api({test: 'hello'});
```

The result on the client side is:

```
print turn context { test: 'hello' }
before post call...:1
result Promise { <pending> }
[ 'body\n', { test: 'hello' } ]
```

Note:

- That line of code `return JSON.stringify(err);` isn't necessary. The callback in a promise is not expecting any return unless you want to use it for flow control purposes.
- if body is indeed undefined, you will have an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks @Jperl for the response. We are able to get the proper result when there is no time delay in post (we are using your approach only). now issue is: We call our post method and it performs some operations and it takes around 20 secs to respond back, because of this we are getting only Json body but not in "TurnContext" (resolve([json_body,turnContext]). can you please help us

Comment: I have no idea. Wihtout more information and what you're doing, I can't help you. No matter how long it takes for the server to respond, you should still have turnContext. If turnContext is an object and you're modifying it in the meantime, then you will get a modified turnContext in resolve since objects are passed by reference. What are you getting for turnContext?

Comment: Well, not really by reference, the value itself is a reference. That's why if you assign a new literal object to turnContext outside of the function after calling initPromise, turnContext in initPromise won't change (it will keep its reference to the original object). However, if you change one of his properties (turnContext.prop = something), it will also change the object in initPromise.

Comment: Thanks @Jperl . We are really stuck in getting back that TurnContext because of the delay. Can we get connected in LinkedIn/Social network as so we can explain more in details. This will help us a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

This will work for the latest node.js versions.

```
async initPromise(turnContext)
        {
            var res;
            var fs = require('fs');
            var request = require('request');
            var formData1 = {image1: "Hello"};
            var path = require('path')
            var base_dir=path.dirname(path.dirname(__filename))
            console.log(path.join( base_dir, "resource", "output.png"));
            var image_name = path.join( base_dir, "resource", "output.png")
            var formData = { image1: fs.createReadStream(image_name) };
            var json_body = "" ;
            var obj_value= "";

            return await new Promise(function(resolve,reject)
            {
                console.log("pls work",turnContext);
                //\var turnContext1 = turnContext;
                //\console.log(typeof(turnContext));
                console.error('before post call...:1');
                request.post({url:'http://127.0.0.1:5002/',formData: formData}, (err, httpResponse, body) =>
                    {
                            console.log("formdata....body....",formData);
                            console.log("inside request post");
                            if (err) {
                                reject(err);
                            }
                            else{
                                if (body != undefined) {
                                json_body = JSON.parse(body);
                                console.log("response inside", json_body);

                                resolve([json_body,turnContext]); //here we are not able to get the turncontext
                                } else {
                                    reject('body undefined');
                                    }
                            }

                        });
                    });
        }

async flask_api(turnContext) {
        var result = await this.initPromise(turnContext);
        console.log("result", result);
        console.log("result1", result[0]);
        console.log("result2", result[1]);



}
```